# Intercept VM Save/Maintenance Mode Request

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, system-center

I have a Hyper-V VM running in Windows Server 2016 that is being managed through System Center. The VM has a device connected via DDA; therefore, the VM cannot enter the save state. This means that attempts to place the host in Maintenance Mode will fail.

Is there a way I can intercept a request for maintenance mode so I can send a signal to the guest OS? Furthermore, can I postpone the maintenance mode to give the guest time to react?

My current workaround is to manually signal the guest OS, then enter maintenance mode via the `Disable-SCVMHost` cmdlet, but I would prefer to do it from System Center.

Comment: I assume that System Center you mentioned is System Center Virtual Machine Manager exactly. If so, I think there are two methods: 1. In VMM Console, manually shut down VM before staring maintenance mode, and then perform maintenance mode from VMM console. 2. Develop console add-in in VMM, the add-in can perform signal VM, and then start maintenance mode. 3. develop a Powershell script, which has the same function as console add-in.

Comment: @AndyLiu-MSFT yes, I was referring to the VMM. I will look into developing a console add-in.

Comment: You can find the guide and examples for VMM add-in SDK from the link below. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

If you've passed through a PCI device to the guest, the VM can't really move to another host.  And as long as that is true, why are you marking it as a cluster resource?  Just make it an unclustered VM and then the cluster service won't track it, and you'll be able to put the host in maintenance mode.

Comment: I believe we're using System Center to allow for additional features not present in i.e. the Hyper-V Manager.